# "Could not Find Server in sys.servers" when deleting, but OK when selecting

Tags: sql-server

We're currently having an issue with one of our linked servers.

if I run this code it works

```
SELECT *
FROM [LINKEDSERVER].[databasename].dbo.[tablename] a
INNER JOIN [localdb].dbo.[localtable] b
on b.somefield = a.somefield
```

But this fails

```
DELETE FROM a 
FROM [LINKEDSERVER].[databasename].dbo.[tablename] a
INNER JOIN [localdb].dbo.[localtable] b
on b.somefield = a.somefield
```

giving error:

```
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server <servername> returned message "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.".
Msg 7202, Level 11, State 2, Line 1
Could not find server <servername> in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.
```

The linked server does appear in sys.sysservers, and I've tried dropping and readding the linked server, to no effect:

```
exec sp_dropserver <servername>, droplogins
exec sp_addserver <servername>
exec sp_serveroption <servername>, 'data access' , 'true'
```

Linked server is SQL 2005, linking server is 2008R2

In case this is relevant (and it seems possible), I recently migrated the SQL server to which we're linking to new hardware (with new SQL install etc.) and changed the IP of new hardware server back to that of old server for continuity. In all other respects this has worked fine. We never had this problem on the old server.

Comment: Hi @DanBennett ..did you find any solution to the problem?

Comment: Sorry this is a few years ago now and I just can't remember either way. I would guess that my next step would be to try running the code on the server which held the table I wanted to delete from. Obviously that's not going to work in every case. In general I try to avoid Linked Servers for a whole host of reasons, though of course you don't always get to choose - you sometimes inherit things.